# How to avoid react minified warning

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am suffering from this warning for several days and don't know why this config doesn't work. I already added DefinePlugin,  however, I am still getting "Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React.".

Any clue about this? Thanks!

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "release":"NODE_ENV=production webpack",
   },
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.0.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "~15.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.29.5",
    "react-dom": "~15.0.1",
    "react-select-box": "^3.0.1"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "uglify-js-plugin": "0.0.6",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

***webpack.config.js***

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');    

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        Page: './page.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: '/',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Remove the `UglifyJsPlugin` from your webpack config (for debugging).

Comment: The warning did not log to the console when I removed the `UglifyJsPlugin`. It looks like the `DefinePlugin` only selectively updates instances of `process.env.NODE_ENV` - i.e. the condition inside the method to print the warning is updated to `if (false)` but the condition in the react code still says `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`. It seems the `UglifyJsPlugin` removes the code inside the `if (false)` block but the react code is unchanges, and then `process.env.NODE` is undefined at runtime

Comment: With `DefinePlugin` only: `var warning = emptyFunction; if (false) { ...`. With `DefinePlugin` and `UglifyJsPlugin`: `warning=emptyFunction;"production"!==process.env.NODE_ENV&&!function(){ ...` So it looks like maybe the `DefinePlugin` is not being run or it's run after `UglifyJsPlugin`... I have tried reordering the plugin list in the webpack config and get the same result

Comment: Update: my problem was actually from a dependency (`react-data-grid-addons`) which has incorrectly embedded the full react code inside its distribution.

Comment: For people like me who want to fix the problem with `react-data-grid-addons`, @supamanda has filled [an issue on github](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/675).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below conifiguration in plugins

```
new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      // Don't beautify output (enable for neater output)
      beautify: false,

      // Eliminate comments
      comments: false,

      // Compression specific options
      compress: {
        warnings: false,

        // Drop `console` statements
        drop_console: true
      },
    })
```

Comment: I don't think this is an ideal solution because it just removes all instances of `console.log`